# Resampling and filtering to the same frequency data in Python

Tags: python, database, filtering, signal-processing, downsampling

I'm working with a large amount of data that comes in daily at 32hz. We want to filter the data to .5hz(Edit: Question originally specified 1hz, changed based on suggestion) as well as down sample it to 1hz. I am using signal.resample for down sampling and signal.filtfilt with a signal.butter filter. However after performing both of these the FFT shows the signal fall off around 0.16hz.

Does the order that you filter than downsample matter? Is it something to do with the procedures? Am I not understanding the methods right?

I included the data that I think is relevant

```
desiredFreq = 1 * 60 *60 *26

# untouched data
quickPlots(x,32) # 32 hz

# filtered
x = ft.butterLowPass(x, .5, 32)
quickPlots(x,32) # 32 hz

# resampled
x = ft.resampleData(x, desiredFreq)
quickPlots(x,1) # should be 1 hz


def butterLowPass(data,desired,original,order = 5):
    """ Creates the coefficients for a low pass butterworth
    filter. That can change data from its original sample rate
    to a desired sample rate

Args: 
----
    data (np.array): data to be filtered
    desirerd (int): the cutoff point for data in hz
    original (int): the initial sampling rate in hz

Returns:
-------
    np.array: of the data after it has been filtered

Note:
----
    I find that the filter will make the data all 0's if the order
is too high. Not sure if this is my end or scipy.signal. So work with
CAUTION

References:
----------
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate
"""
nyq = .5 * original
cutoff = desired / nyq
b, a = signal.butter(order, cutoff, btype = 'lowpass', analog = False)

return signal.filtfilt(b, a, data, padlen =10)

def resampleData(data, desired):
    """ Takes in a set of data and resamples the data at the 
    desired frequency.



Args:
----
    data (np.array): data to be operated on
    desired (int): the desired sampled points 
        over the dataset

Returns:
-------
    np.array: of the resamples data

Notes:
-----
    Since signal.resample works MUCH faster when the len of 
data is a power of 2, we pad the data at the end with null values
and then discard them after.
"""
nOld = len(data)    
thispow2 = np.floor(np.log2(nOld))
nextpow2 = np.power(2, thispow2+1)

data = np.lib.pad(
        data, 
        (0,int(nextpow2-nOld)), 
        mode='constant',
        constant_values = (0,0)
        )

nNew = len(data)
resample = int(np.ceil(desired*nNew/nOld)) 


data = signal.resample(data, resample)    
data = data[:desired]
return data

def quickPlots(data,fs):
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy import signal
    import time
    fft,pxx=signal.welch(data,fs)
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.show()
    plt.loglog(fft,pxx)
    plt.show()
```

Pictures of FFT:

Raw data(4hz spike due to other frequencies leaking in):
[image: Raw data(4hz spike due to other frequencies leaking in)]

After filtfilt:
[image: After filtfilt]

After resample:
[image: After resample]

Edit: After adjusting to filter at .5hz the same problem appears. I am now wondering if it is a problem with how I am displaying my FFT. I've included the quick plotting I was using to display the graphs.

Comment: filter 1st, you have to remove everything with frequency components above your target fs/2 -  if you want 1 Hz sample rate after decimation the data has to be filtered to below 1/2 Hz before the decimation step

Comment: I'll give this a try soon. The remote station went down so I have to deal with that first.

Comment: @f5r5e5d I've made the suggested change and it appears that there is the same problem. I'm wondering now if its a problem with how I am displaying the FFT. I've updated the code snippet to illustrate the graphing in the OP.

Comment: @f5r5e5d Believe I've figured out the solution with the graphs. Will update soon.